# Are all MVC models lightweight?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I was first introduced to the idea of a model when I learned WPF. The MVVM concept of a model seems to be more aligned to general 'business logic' encased in a class/set of classes. When I look at MVC though, the model seems to be lightweight-classes that are "passed" to and from the user via forms. Is this assessment correct, or are there situations where a model is something heavier (does more than just hold and validate data input from the user).

Comment: In the context of ASP.NET MVC, I tend to call business-logic objects with methods and stuff "Models" and the lightweight classes that get passed to and from forms "ViewModels". The former is the M in MVC; the latter is (in my opinion) a part of the communication between V and C; in essence it's kind of M-C-VM-V rather than MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Models (classes) as data container (which i usually do) , look at anemic domain model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model), then you can implement business layer, service, data layer independently.

Or you can implement them within your model, which some folks wants to do that due to encapsulation, and several design priciples.

Look into domain driven design as well. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)

Comment: The first link shows `This article may be confusing or unclear to readers` in the header. I think that's pretty spot on.

Comment: You can google it further and read up on martin fowler's thought on that, but then there are other school of thoughts on that. i like it.

Comment: Not intending to be critical, but "google it" seems sort of counter to the stackoverflow philosophy.

Comment: I think it is appropriate on SO to point someone in the right direction and encourage them to learn further on their own, rather than writing up a long treatise on a subject.

Comment: Oh, I don't disagree with that. But I feel like my central question - "is there a conceptual difference between the models in WPF/MVVM vs. MVC" - hasn't really been answered. I got a couple of links to Wikipedia (which I appreciate) but I don't feel as though I've really made any progress.

Comment: To me, it looks like your question was "Are all MVC models lightweight?" and you got someone's expert opinion (no, it can be done either way), that expert's preference (lightweight), and some good keywords to do further research.  Maybe you can post a more specific question, like "What are the conceptual differences between the models in WPF/MVVM vs. MVC?"

Comment: Ah, ok. That's my misunderstanding. I guess I just needed it spelled out for me. Thanks both.

Comment: There is really not a right answer for this question and there is lot of discussion around this topic between architects. Some architects prefer anemic, some doesn't like it.

Comment: Interesting. I'm reading around trying to understand what the anemic domain model is, but I can't find a good definition for it. I saw the Wikipedia link, and Martin Fowler's page, and both seem to be against it, but I don't fully understand what 'it' is.

Comment: :) that s the problem with it. Anemic domain model is, using the object as a data container. So there is no object related logic is implemented within class definition. Whereas in DOmain driven design and in other principles, such as encapsulation, arcitects say that business logic should belong to class.

Comment: In MVC projects I use Model as data container and implement the business as a layer or in other classes, such as controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well in MVC or another similar Design Pattern you have defined 3 separate layers of your application. The model with the logic of your objects, the view for showing and getting information from the user, and then a controller witch does the interaction and exchanges between the 2.

MVC is more used for web apps and MVVM with WPF. The reason is that you with WPF can do the databinding of the objects in your View with the one in the ViewModel.

For example a Twiter app: You can do have a model (tweetItem) with all the properties of a Tweet, a ViewModel that gets and stores the tweets in an collection and view that has a list, for showing them, binded to that collection.

There for MVVM or MVC only impact in your app is on how the code is organized.